# "preempts no lexical conventions" in a Scheme PL report

Tags: standards, scheme

I am reading "Revised^5 Report on the Algorithmic Language Scheme," "1.3.1. Primitive, library, and optional features."

> In particular, implementations must support portable code by providing
>   a syntactic mode that preempts no lexical conventions of this report.

I don't understand this passage. Maybe it's because English is not my native language. My dictionary does not offer a meaning of the verb "preempt" that makes the passage meaningful. A little clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What they're saying is that a conforming implementation must provide a syntactic mode that complies exactly with the lexical conventions of the report.  It may ALSO provide ways to change the conventions, but it is absolutely positively required to provide a "plain Vanilla" "just like the Report" mode.

"Preempting a lexical convention" means doing something different.  When they say "preempt no conventions", they mean it must not do anything different.